# Libreoffice Writer — How do I select which Paragraph Styles appear in the toolbar drop-down menu?

Tags: user-interface, styles, libreoffice-writer

I mainly use LibreOffice Writer as a rich text editor to write short stories, and as such I generally use the "First Line Indent" style on my text. However, this Style doesn't appear in the Set Paragraph Style drop-down menu on the toolbar, meaning that I need to open the sidebar menu and select it from the big list in order to utilize it.

For convenience, I've tried to find a way to customize the drop-down so as to include the First Line Indent style, but it doesn't appear to be listed in the Customize window, and my searches into the topic have yielded no answer. Is this possible to do, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't (directly), but there are some workarounds.

- Create a custom style based on "First Line Indent" (right-click on the style in the formatter window and select "New..."), so it's available among the custom styles; thus, the First Line Indent style will be available by hitting <kbd>F11</kbd>;
- Alternatively, add the "First Line Indent" style to the Styles Menu (Tools -> Customize -> Menus -> ...). Thus, it's available on <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> and the styles menu (you may even assign a keybord shortcut to the style itself);
- Dirty hack: create a custom template and apply the "First Line Indent" style anywhere (maybe header or footer, if you don't use them for displaying content; maybe a frame added anywhere). If it's applied in the document this way, it should appear in the dropdown as well as in the "Applied Styles" list.